# javascript format for mozilla

Tags: javascript

what is the equallent of window.event.clientX for mozilla in javascript?
This is my code, function called in body-> **onbeforeunload="return CloseOrNotClose(event);"**

This is fine for ie but not working in mozilla.

```
function CloseOrNotClose(event) {

var ie = document.all;
if (ie) {
           if ((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY < 0)) {
                    return "Your Information related to this exam will be lost and you will have to reappear for it, \nDo you want to continue?";
             }
}
else {
    if ((event.clientX < 0) || (event.clientY < 0)) 
    return "Your Information related to this exam will be lost and you will have to reappear for it, \nDo you want to continue?";
}
```

}

Comment: In all other browsers, the `event` object is passed as parameter to the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer has `window.event.clientX`

Mozilla has:

```
function show_coords(event)
{
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  alert("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);
}
```

edit1:

> function called in body-> onbeforeunload="return CloseOrNotClose(event);"

I think it only works for Mozilla as `window.onbeforeunload = CloseOrNotClose;`

edit2:

> *Note that in Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user.*

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: Grab jQuery and use that - it really helps smooth out browser inconsistencies and makes javascript enjoyable instead of annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your entire function you've been using?

This works for me:

```
function getXY(e)
{
  var e=(!e) ? window.event : e;
  var X = 0;
  var Y = 0;

  if(e.pageX)
  {
    X = e.pageX + window.pageXOffset;
    Y = e.pageY + window.pageYOffset;
  }
```